# Detect directory changes in unix

Tags: linux, bash, unix, filesystems

How could I track changes of specific directory in UNIX? For example, I launch some utility which create some files during its execution. I want to know what exact files were created during one particular launch. Is there any simple way to get such information? Problem is that:

1. I cannot flush directory content after script execution
2. Files created with the name that has hash as a compound part. There is no possibility to get this hash from script for subsequent search.
3. There could be several scripts executed simultaneously, I do not want to see files created by another process in the same folder.

Please notice that I do not want to know whether directory has been changed as stated [here](http://valeriu.palos.ro/169/recursive-filedirectory-change-detection/), I need filenames which ideally could be grepped to match specific pattern.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to subscribe to [file system change notifications](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).

Answer (score 3):

You should use something like FAM, gamin, or inotify to detect when a file has been created, closed, etc.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `strace -f myscript` to trace all system calls made by the script, and use `grep` to filter the system calls that create new files.

Comment: You can actually ask `strace` to filter the syscalls it shows you itself, using `-e trace=file` (which shows all filename-using syscalls).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`script`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/script) command to track the commands launched.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Linux Auditing System. Here is a howto link:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html